# Local eventEmitter listening to global eventEmitter

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

I almost wrote the question title as - **Communicating between eventEmitters**

I have a node.js module (X) that is on the global scope (it uses eventEmitter). I then have code that is local to each socket (user connected).

right now i am carrying X through the process on a global variable G={'X':X} so that the socket can then access X like this:

```
G.X.on('someEvent',doSomething);
```

This is dumb! Now every time i start my server it seems to act fine (I receive the event), but then if I refresh the page and emit an event I get it twice. If I refresh the page again I get the event 3 times.

I think that I am binding the listener to the same eventEmitter that is global.

How can I make a separate local eventListener to listen for the emits of the global eventEmiter?

I know how to set up an eventEmiter:

```
var events = require('events');
var ee = new events.EventEmitter();

ee.on('someEvent',function(){console.log('hello');});
```

but it does not catch the event of another...

I have also tried copying the module using the eventEmitter

```
var ee = G.X;
ee.on('someEvent',function() { console.log('hello'); });
```

But it still receives multiples of an event.

```
hello
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked quite some time ago, but here's my answer anyways, seeing as there's no answer for it yet.

Listen to the socket object's "close" event, then remove the callbacks to your global. So it would look like:

```
X.addListener("someEvent", callback);

X.on("someEvent", function(socket){
  socket.on("close", function(){
    X.removeListener("someEvent", callback);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey could you extrapolate your answer to this question I posted recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031278/interaction-between-expressjs-socket-io-and-eventemitter-listeners